# Import issues mystery characters

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, importexport

I used magestore store manager to consolidate several magento installations into a unified multi store

when i did the product exports and imports toconsolidate it all i now hiow a cpl issues

products with custom options cannot be added to the cart unless i edit and save the product, dont need to add the custom options they are already there just need to open and save it again ....?? any fast way to do this got 2k products

2nd issue maybe i can soplve this with a sql query via phpmyadmin not sure not a sql expert however after import I got this for example it has this extra character  Â

this has been spewed into most product descriptions by the store manager process any one got a awesome sql query i can run to remove these offending characters?

Watts:Â 375

Amp Draw:Â 27.17

LED's:Â 100

Raw Lumens:Â 364,000

Continous Arc Intensity:Â 325,000

Continous Arc Width:Â 44.3

Continous Arc Distance:Â 1,206.6

Answer (score 0):

About your first issue, do you see the data in your database? If so, please check if the same data is also in the flat tables, if you're using them. I'm not familiar with the extension you're using, but maybe the above will help.

The second is a charset issue. Probably because your site/database is UTF-8 and the data you imported wasn't (i.e. it was latin1). Make sure that the charset of your database and the file(s) you want to import have the same charset, this should solve the issue.